# Is it possible to select text in zathura without the mouse?

Tags: pdf, mupdf

It is kind of annoying to use the mouse every time I have to copy text from a PDF in [zathura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura_(document_viewer)).

I was wondering if it is possible to select and copy text in zathura similar to Vim's visual mode? I did a Google search but couldn't find anything.

I use zathura-pdf-mupdf on manjaro with xfce.

Comment: nope. the quickest thing is the double click bottom-right-ish and drag a little to select the entire page (double clicking starts selection from the top-left to where your cursor is), but this doesn't select the last one or two lines even if you select the entire page. Selection in zathura **_`REALLY`_** needs some work.

Comment: This question seems more related for [su] than [so]

Answer (score 10):

As of Jan '20, the zathura [official documentation](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/documentation/) is being reworked and does not contain anything related to usage.

Looking at the [man docs](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/blob/develop/doc%2Fman%2F_bindings.txt), it seems that zathura does not come with select / copy keybindings that mimic Vim's visual mode. The closest that comes to it is scrolling with h, k, j, l. [Here's the full list](https://man.cx/zathura(1)#heading6) of mouse and key bindings.

Feel free to open a [feature request](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/issues).